# Check if MethodDeclaration similar to an IMethod

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Is there any way by which i can compare a MethodDeclaration object and IMethod object and check whether they are similar? Or is there any way by whcih a MethodDeclaration object can be converted to an IMethod object (IMethod provides a isSimilar function)?

**Update :** Similarily i would like to know if a FieldDeclaration can be converted to a IField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MethodDeclaration is an ASTNode, and IMethod is a JavaElement. The definitive way to check if these two objects correspond to the same method is to compare their Binding.

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#From_an_ASTNode_to_an_IBinding and http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#From_an_IJavaElement_to_an_IBinding on how to get the Binding for an ASTNode and for a JavaElement. Once you have the Binding or the Binding key you can just compare that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to extract the IMethod out of an MethodDeclaration using `IMethod method = (IMethod) methoDeclarationNode.resolveBinding().getJavaElement();` I then compared the two IMethods using isSimilar method.

But FieldDeclaration doesn't have a resolveBinding method. In the link provided it is mentioned that ASTParser.createBindings can be used to create an IBinding, but that requires a progressMonitor. Can the progress monitor be specified as null?

Comment: Also can u please let know, how one can get the binding key from the FieldDeclarationNode. There is no info on the FAQ for finding the javaElement of an AST Node.

Comment: Yes, the progress monitor can be null.

Comment: @DeepakAzad Thank you so much.. This really helped!