# FieldDeclaration to IField - Getting IBinding from FieldDeclaration

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

How can a `FieldDeclaration` (type: ASTNode) be converted to an `IField` (type: JavaElement). Is it possible to get the binding from the FieldDeclaration ASTNode, just like node.resolveBinding() as for MethodDeclaration node.

**Need** : I am visiting a FieldDeclaration node in a Class having public constants, and want to search references for that field in the project. I am using JDT's SearchEngine for same. For this I want to create a search pattern as follows :

```
SearchPattern.createPattern(iField, IJavaSearchConstants.REFERENCES);
```

I have asked this as a comment to one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309824/check-if-methoddeclaration-similar-to-an-imethod), but didn't get the answer for same. Posting it as separate question.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

---

In reply to Deepak's answer.

Using your approach i can retrieve the JavaElement as follows

```
List<VariableDeclarationFragment> fragments = node.fragments();
VariableDeclarationFragment fragment = fragments.get(0);
IJavaElement fieldElement = fragment.resolveBinding().getJavaElement();
```

If i am passing this IJavaElement to create the search pattern instead of the IField will it return the same result as those for an IField.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual ASTView plugin is your friend! :-) In the ASTView you can see that binding is available for VariableDeclarationFragment but not for a FieldDeclaration.

Getting the binding from FieldDeclaration

- Get the 'fragments' of the FieldDeclaration => you now have a bunch of VariableDeclarationFragment nodes
- Call VariableDeclarationFragment#resolveBinding() (this method is inherited from VariableDeclaration)

Comment: I have updated the question with my query on your answer. Please reply.

Comment: For debugging purpose do an instanceof check on 'fieldElement' it should be the correct 'IField'.

Comment: just checked and yes it is an instance of IField. Thanks a lot.