# How to use jdt java model to get the line number of a field in a java class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.IField

IField field = IType.createField(contents, null, true, null);
```

How to get the line number of field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the line number of an ASTNode using the below code

```
ASTNode node = compilationUnit.findDeclaringNode(field.getKey());

int lineNumber = compilationUnit.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()) - 1;
```

Note that this will work only if the bindings are resolved.

Refer the below links for more details:

- [eclipse ASTNode to source code line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126857/eclipse-astnode-to-source-code-line-number/11131452#11131452)
- [FieldDeclaration to IField - Getting IBinding from FieldDeclaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131793/fielddeclaration-to-ifield-getting-ibinding-from-fielddeclaration)

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ListRewrite.insertLast(node, null), how to get the line number of node?

Comment: couldn't understand your comment, can u explain a bit more?